# Initialize pointer array - cannot make type *[]type

Tags: pointers, go, struct

Its a simple code, saving `car` type objects into a `car` type array. I am trying to use pointer here to pass array reference.

**There are 2 problems:**

**1** - I can't initialize it as empty array. When I use `make`, it says:

> cannot make type *[]car

**2** - If I don't use `make`, runtime error occurs:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

---

**Code:**

```
import "fmt"

type car struct {
    plate string
    color string
}

func main() {

    var _cars *[]car        // list of cars
    _cars = make(*[]car, 4) // initialize empty cars list

    saveCar(_cars, car{"ABC-123", "Black"})
    saveCar(_cars, car{"ABC-456", "Black"})
    saveCar(_cars, car{"ABC-789", "Black"})

    fmt.Println(_cars)
}

func saveCar(_cars_list *[]car, _car car) int {

    for index, current := range *_cars_list {
        // if empty place found, save car
        if (car{}) == current {

            // save car
            (*_cars_list)[index] = _car

            // return the saved index
            return index
        }
    }

    return -1
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, of what you are trying to achieve here, what ever you are trying to achieve here, it doesn't seem you are doing it in right way.

Comment: I am trying to create an array and fill it using the function `saveCar`. If I pass the array by value, my main array doesn't get updated. So I tried to pass pointer of array, which is giving me above errors.

Comment: don't you think a map would be better, if you are going to delete values. If not then append would work fine just store the returned array to the same variable. `a = append(a, x...)`

Comment: `tCars := make([]car, 4)
_cars = &tCars`, and by the way we don't use underscores in go.

Comment: Your last comment, it did the job. I passed `&tCars` to my function. Post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing this would make your code work:

```golang
tCars := make([]car, 4)
_cars = &tCars
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - cannot make type *[]car

You observe it because `make` creates slice, map or chan. In the example you gave you tried to create pointer to a slice which is none of the typed `make` works with.

> 2 - If I don't use make, runtime error occurs:

that's another problem - you have type "pointer to a slice of car", not "a slice  of car". And in general you need to initialize pointer types before using.

Overall there is no need to use pointer to a slice rather than plain slice in your case, because you don't use append, to there is no chance for reallocation of backed storage.

However, in a real world scenario, when you don't know amount of car instances you are going to add, is much better to use append instead of iterating through slice till the last non-initialized value.

summary:

- to make your program work change *[]car to []car everywhere (example https://play.golang.org/p/lpCtvXqG6UY)
- another (and probably better) way is to use append instead of saveCar (don't forget to use returned value in case of happened re-allocation, example: https://play.golang.org/p/L8V10tSb-IJ)